# How to migrate from SAP BO to COGNOS?

Tags: cognos, business-objects

I want to migrate SAP BO to cognos using SAP BO meta data. Can any know is there any tool to do this OR any suggestion to resolve this task.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Framework Manager metadata wizard has a third party metadata sources option.   There's a number of BO options in the list.

This will allow you to migrate your UNV to a FM model.  I've never worked with BO so I can't say to what degree of fidelity the mapping will be.  You will need to review the model afterwards and you will probably need to do additional modelling.

[image]